# Turning multi-fasta file into set of single-line sequences

Tags: regex, shell, parsing, fasta

I have a multi-fasta sequence file (there is a newline character at the end of each line):

```
>M3559
GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA
TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTATGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG
CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTC
>M9171
GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA
TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG
CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTACCTC
>M4692
GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA
TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG
CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTC
```

I would like to turn it into a file where each sequence is in a single line, with sequence name followed by tab:

```
>M3559 GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCATTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTATGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACGCTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTC
>M9171 GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCATTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACGCTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTACCTC
>M4692 GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCATTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACGCTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTC
```

I got to the point where I removed all the newline characters by simple:

```
awk 1 ORS='' test.txt
```

But I now need to place a newline character in the beginning of each sequence name (so substitute > with \n>)

```
tr ">" "\n"
```

(although this removes the >, and ideally I would like to keep it, but it's not a big deal)

and add a \t after the sequence name, which I can capture with a regular expression.

```
^>M[0-9]{4}
```

And this is this last bit I struggle with - how do I add a character after a regex-ed string in a file? Suggestions will be greatly appreciated :-)

yot

**UPDATE: below I paste the output of the various commands suggested by others on my test input file.**

**UPDATE 2: Fredrik's answer works if you use gnu sed instead of the default sed on a Mac. Please see my comment under Fredrik's answer.**

Running:

```
awk -v RS='\n>' -v ORS='\n>' -v OFS='' -F'\n' '{$1=$1 "\t"}1' file
```

on my input produces:

```
>M3559
>GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA
>TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTATGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG
>CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTC
>ATCCTATTATTTATCGCACCTACGTTCAATATTACAGGCGAACATACTTA
>CTAAAGTGTGTTAATTAATTAATGCTTGTAGGACATAATAATAACAATTG
>>M9171
>GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA
>TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG
>CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTACCTC
>ATCCTATTATTTATCGCACCTACGTTCAATATTACAGGCGAGCATACTTA
>CTAAAGTGTGTTAGTTAATTAATGCTTGTAGGACATAATAATAACAATTG
>>M4692
>GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA
>TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG
>CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTC
>ATCCTATTATTTATCGCACCTACGTTCAATATTACAGGCGAACATACTTA
>CCAAAATGTGTTAATTAATTAATGCTTGTAGGACATAATAATAACAATTG
```

Running:

```
echo $(cat test.txt) | sed 's/>/\n>/2g' | sed 's/ //2g' | sed 's/ /\t/g'
```

produces nothing (no output).

I am not running `paste -d " " - - - - < input` as numbers of line for each sequence is different in my input.

But running:

```
awk 'NR%4{printf $0" ";next;}1' input
```

Produces:

```
>M3559 GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTATGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTC
ATCCTATTATTTATCGCACCTACGTTCAATATTACAGGCGAACATACTTA CTAAAGTGTGTTAATTAATTAATGCTTGTAGGACATAATAATAACAATTG 
>M9171 GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA
TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTACCTC ATCCTATTATTTATCGCACCTACGTTCAATATTACAGGCGAGCATACTTA CTAAAGTGTGTTAGTTAATTAATGCTTGTAGGACATAATAATAACAATTG
>M4692 GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTC
ATCCTATTATTTATCGCACCTACGTTCAATATTACAGGCGAACATACTTA CCAAAATGTGTTAATTAATTAATGCTTGTAGGACATAATAATAACAATTG
```

and then running sed `'s/ \+/ /' | tr -d ' '` does not help...

Comment: This looks like some chimpanzee genome...

Comment: Nope, but close enough ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is as well formated as above, you can use `paste`

```
$ paste -d " " - - - - < input
>M3559 GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTATGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTC
>M9171 GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTACCTC
>M4692 GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTC
```

or `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR%4{printf $0" ";next;}1' input
>M3559 GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTATGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTC
>M9171 GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTACCTC
>M4692 GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCT:CCATGCA TTTGG:TAT:TTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACG CTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTC
```

To remove spaces and to have a tab after the id, pipe everything to

```
sed 's/ \+/ /' | tr -d ' '
```

Comment: This doesn't work either - both your solutions leave space at the end of each line. I need a tab after sequence id (>M3559) and the rest of the lines of each sequenced joined with no spaces.

Comment: Well, use `sed` to replace first occurrence of spaces with a tab and remove the rest of the spaces. Trivial and is left as an exercise...

Comment: I have now marked this answer as the correct one, but with two caveats:
1. It only works with gnu sed, and not with the default sed on a Mac. I installed gnu sed on my Mac and it worked.
2. There is a small mistake in the sed command, as it introduces space in place of the first space and not the tab. The correct pipe to do what I want is therefore:

`awk 'NR%4{printf $0" ";next;}1' input | sed 's/ \+/\t/' | tr -d " "`

Sorry it took me so long, but what a relief it bloody works! Thanks a lot Fredrik!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with awk:

```
awk -v RS='\n>' -v ORS='\n>' -v OFS='' -F'\n' '{$1=$1 "\t"}1' file
```

The idea is to set the input and output records separator to `\n>` and the fields separator to `\n`. With this setting, the first field is the sequence name. All you need is to set the output fields separator to the empty string and to append a tab character at the end of this field.

Comment: This doesn't work - I think the reason is that you're not aware that at the end of each line of my input file is a newline character... Your script adds tabs all right, but to each line of the input. I will amend my description.

Comment: This is script is designed for your original file (not the one after `awk 1 ORS=''...`). It has been tested and works well. I obviously know that lines are separated by a newline (otherwise they are not lines).

Comment: I did run it on my original file. It still produces tabs at the end of each line (it behaves equivalent to tr "\n" "\t"... Could a different version of awk be a reason? I am on Mac El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be very elegant but I think it does what you want:

```
echo $(cat test.txt) | sed 's/>/\n>/2g' | sed 's/ //2g' | sed 's/ /\t/g'
```

Explained:

`echo $(cat test.txt)` will linearize the file

`sed 's/>/\n>/2g'` - places a `'\n'` before `'>'` (from 2nd ocurrence on)

`sed 's/ //2g'` - will delete the spaces after the first occurrence

`sed 's/ /\t/g'` - replace the only space left for a tab

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: Thanks, but no... In particular you can't substitute multiple characters with sed (at least not with a newline character)... I will update my original question with the output of the various ideas presented here...

Comment: newline is like any other character and can be replaced multiple times.
Whats your EOL char? `\r\n` (windows) or just `\n` (Unix)?

Comment: Yeah, one of the newlines was not Unix, but I normalised all one endings to \n and still none of the solutions on this page work.